# Scriptaculous Ajax.Autocompleter fails in IE9 and FF5

Tags: javascript, ajax, scriptaculous

A particular web-page which makes use of Ajax.Autocompleter by Scriptaculous has been working ok for ever both in IE and FF.
It turns out that it no longer works in FF5 nor IE9.
My findings are:

- The Ajax requests are posted to the server and successfully returned. The choices-div does not appear however.
- IE9 works fine if I force it to IE8 compatibility

Web-page is using latest Prototype 1.7 and Scriptaculous 1.9

Has anyone got issues with Ajax.Autocompleter in IE9 or FF5?
Thank you.
Bart

Comment: What else would one expect from software released 8 months ago?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have things working now: turns out the Ajax responses cannot have an XML processing instruction, `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`

Omitting this instruction and simply returning `<ul><li>...</li><li>...</li></ul>` makes things work flawlessly.

I welcome other suggestions.